# alter content administration page (admin/content)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on some drupal installation and googled the whole day, but I can't figure out an answer to the following question:

How is it possible to alter the admin/content page in a way that specific roles are only able to see or filter out limited content types?

Please notice that I don't want to restrict node access in general, I just want to make this page less confusing for editors with different roles and tasks.

I know there is the administration views module and there I can set filter fields in the way I want. The problem with this is that I'm not able to enter the views access restrictions and so all I can do is limit the view's content types for all roles.

Can somebody give me a hint how to solve this?

Thank you very much and sorry for bad english.

Comment: after googling again i found that approach and got it working...
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/17363

i basically understood it but it does not affect the content types provided for the filter-dropdown. and could someone give me a hint how that line works:

`$query->where($alias.'.type IN (:types)', array(':types' => 'article'));`

how can i add multiple content-type-names?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make a custom module.

In this module you would create a page with `hook_menu()`.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

Then in the page callback function that you create you load `global $user` and switch between the `$user->roles`, out putting different HTML lists of links depending on their role. If you want something a little more dynamic you can always load the various content types with `node_type_get_types()`.

Then go into `structure -> menus -> navigation` and disable the default link, replacing it with the new page you created.

If you aren't 100% clear on how to do a couple of these things comment here and I will update my answer.

Comment: ok, this is about how to rebuild the content-administration-page respectively creating a custom content administration and replace the original one? am i right?

so there is no way to affect the original one?

Comment: ok, thank you for your advice, but isnt that a very common problem so there should be an out-of-the-box-solution or at least a module? am I the only one facing that with some 20 content types and a user role with just access to one of it?

Comment: but if i restrict permissions to view some nodes or content types, they are still being listed on the content administration page?! and that listing is what i am trying to prevent.

Comment: but this still does not prevent it from being listed? maybe an example to make this clear:
i have 100 nodes of a content type "simple page" + 100 nodes of type "cooking recipes".
now i have a role with only add/edit/delete "cooking recipes". but in the content list
he still has 200 nodes, 100 of them aren't his business. that may be no problem
cause he now can filter out his "cooking recipes"... but this gets complicated when having 20 content types
and around 2000 nodes. the "cooking recipes"-editor now gets listed 2000 nodes in which 1900 aren't his business.

Comment: Your best option is to build a drop-in replacement. Either with views or a custom module.